# Use batch file to change PC name

Tags: batch-file

So I'm trying to change my PC name using a batch file but when i run this code as administrator:

```
set /P PCNAME=Please enter Laptop Name:
set PCOLD=hostname
WMIC computersystem Where Name="%PCOLD%" Call rename "%PCNAME%"
```

It gives this error message:
"No Instances available"

and if i replace "%PCOLD%" with hostname it gives this error message:

```
WMIC computersystem Where Name=hostname Call rename "%PCNAME%"
```

"ERROR:
Description = Invalid query"

Comment: Are you running this locally on the target PC? Is the PC really named `hostname`? What is the output of `%ComputerName%`, `[ENTER]`ed in a Command Prompt window? Do you even need to use a `WHERE` clause, _(have you tried just using `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe CompterSystem Call Rename…`)_? If this is being run remotely, you will need to provide more details, especially the target OS, and if part of a domain, we would also need to know more information about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Wmic ComputerSystem where Caption='%ComputerName%' rename example
```

Comment: `Rename` is a method which should be `CALL`ed. Open a Command Prompt window, type `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe ComputerSystem /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key. You should see that the options at that point are `ASSOC`, `CALL`, `CREATE`, `DELETE`, `GET`, `LIST`, and `SET`. If you then `[ENTER]` `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe ComputerSystem Call /?` you will clearly see the `Rename` method name listed under that option. I would also advise that you do not use the `Caption` property, but instead use the `Name` property. The OP's code actually correctly used both `Call` and `Name`!